# JDO + GoogleAppEngine - search class by value in collection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm making application running on Google App Engine and I'm having problem with getting data using JDO. I have class Message, which has property `private List<String> labels;`. Now I want to have some search function which takes one string (label) as a parameter and searches all messages to get messages with given label. The problem is with the JDO query, right now I have
this (string this.label is a search parameter):

```
   String query = "select from " + Message.class.getName() + " where (labels.contains('" + this.label + "')) ";
```

It works on localhost, but not in GAE (returns NULL). Another (and naive) attempt was

```
   query = "select from " + Note.class.getName() + " where labels=='" + this.label + "'";
```

And it also worked only on localhost, not GAE

Does anybody have an idea how to do that? Thanks for any help

Comment: No idea why things do or dont work, but just to say that the second is not valid JDOQL so best to forget that one. Yes GAE/J people may say they support it but that is a subversion of the JDO spec. The Collection.contains() is a valid method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your statement is wrong. It should be something like:

String query = "SELECT FROM " + Message.class.getName() + 
" WHERE labels.contains(i) && i.label == labelParam " +
" VARIABLES " + Labels.class.getName() + " i " +
" PARAMETER java.lang.String labelParam "

Good Luck